# Neural network with no hidden layers and a linear activation function should approximate a linear regression?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, linear-regression

To my understanding, a neural network will produce the same equation form as a linear regression assuming that you use no hidden layers and a linear activation function. i.e. y = SUM(w_i * x_i + b_i) where i is 0 to the number of features you have.

I've tried to prove this to myself by using the weights and bias of a linear regression, inputting that into a neural network and seeing if the results are the same. They are not.

I am wondering if my understanding is incorrect or if my code is or maybes it's both.

---

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np

linearModel = LinearRegression()
linearModel.fit(np.array(normTrainFeaturesDf), np.array(trainLabelsDf))

# Gets the weights of the linear model and the intercept in a form that can be passed into the neural network
linearWeights = np.array(linearModel.coef_)
intercept = np.array([linearModel.intercept_])

trialWeights = np.reshape(linearWeights, (len(linearWeights), 1))
trialWeights = trialWeights.astype('float32')
intercept = intercept.astype('float32')
newTrialWeights = [trialWeights, intercept]

# Create a neural network and set the weights of the model to the linear model
nnModel = keras.Sequential([keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='linear', input_shape=[len(normTrainFeaturesDf.keys())]),])
nnModel.set_weights(newTrialWeights)

# Print predictions of both models (the results are vastly different)
print(linearModel.predict(np.array(normTestFeaturesDf))
print(nnModel.predict(normTestFeaturesDf).flatten())
```

---

Comment: Have you trained your NN before printing the results ? If you haven't what you're seeing is the predictions of randomly initialized weights.

Comment: @Gabriel_D Doesn't nnModel.set_weights(newTrialWeights) set the weights of the NN to the weights of the linear model?

Comment: Can you please turn this into a reproducible example? `normTrainFeaturesDf` is not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a neural network with a single layer and no activation function is equivalent to linear regression.

Defining some variables you did not include:

```
normTrainFeaturesDf = np.random.rand(100, 10)
normTestFeaturesDf = np.random.rand(10, 10)
trainLabelsDf = np.random.rand(100)
```

Then the output is as expected:

```
>>> linear_model_preds = linearModel.predict(np.array(normTestFeaturesDf))
>>> nn_model_preds = nnModel.predict(normTestFeaturesDf).flatten()

>>> print(linear_model_preds)
>>> print(nn_model_preds)
[0.46030349 0.69676376 0.43064266 0.4583325  0.50750268 0.51753189
 0.47254946 0.50654825 0.52998559 0.35908762]
[0.46030346 0.69676375 0.43064266 0.45833248 0.5075026  0.5175319
 0.47254944 0.50654817 0.52998555 0.3590876 ]
```

The numbers are identical, except for small variations due to float precision.

```
>>> np.allclose(linear_model_preds, nn_model_preds)
True
```